Excel Formula for Today's Month Being Greater Than Lookup Value Month & Provide Message
I have created a budget sheet in Excel to track Debt Snowball payments. I have a formula that successfully works to lookup the month from a list of months (column F) that a final payment is made for a particular column (L), based on there being no further payments entered into that column past the final month:
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,L18:L46<>"",F18:F46,"FAIL",0,-1)

In the above example the date returned is Jul 2024.
What I want to do now, is modify the formula so that it returns either the final month a debt will be paid (if further into the future than the current month), or if the current month is greater than or equal to the month the debt was paid (i.e. the debt was paid off in the current month or in the past) then to return the message "PAID OFF!!"
I have created the following formula to do this:
=IF((MONTH(TODAY())>=(XLOOKUP(TRUE,L18:L46<>"",F18:F46,"FAIL",0,-1))),"PAID OFF!!",(XLOOKUP(TRUE,L18:L46<>"",F18:F46,"FAIL",0,-1)))

However the returned value is simply still "Jul 2024" instead of "PAID OFF!!"
Where am I going wrong with this formula, how do I get it to return "PAID OFF!!" as I intend it to?
Thanks in advance!
ETA screenshot of the sheet to show example data as requested (attached, with values obfuscated for privacy reasons)


Post few of your sample data then show desired output.

Attached a screenshot, desired output is articulated in the question already

Basically you compare the month number today is 7 to a (I don't know exactly) either a string or a date as a number. With high probability the result will be always False

I think I understand that now thanks to your explanation Black cat.
So how do I alter the formula to work?

@LittleMissT, since "paid-off" = non-empty AND 0, you could try =IF((MONTH(TODAY()) >= (XLOOKUP(1, (L18:L46 <> "") *  (L18:L46 = 0), F18:F46, "FAIL", 0, -1))), "PAID OFF!!", XLOOKUP(1,  (L18:L46 <> "") *  (L18:L46 = 0), F18:L46, "FAIL", 0, -1)). Basically to get 'and' you multiply, for 'or' you add (then look for 1 for 'true'.

I have played around a bit and have almost got it working!!
New formula is now this:
=IF((XLOOKUP(TRUE,L18:L46<>"",F18:F46,"FAIL",0,-1)<=TEXT(TODAY(),"mmm yyyy")),"PAID OFF!!",(XLOOKUP(TRUE,L18:L46<>"",F18:F46,"FAIL",0,-1)))

This now shows the value "PAID OFF!!" if the date of the last payment is prior to today's date. It also works for dates in the future, giving the future date.
The only scenario it isn't working for is if the final payment is next month i.e. Aug 2024 - in this case it is returning "PAID OFF!!" when it shouldn't

Instead of comparing to text month-year value (will give unexpected result due alphabetical sort order), compare numerically using <= EOMONTH(TODAY(),0). For today this will be numerical date value for August 31, this year.
